# Appointment booking available time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to get the list of available time for the given date and duration form the tblAppointments table

```
tblAppointments

id int
BookingDate datetime
BookedStartTime datetime
BookedEndTime datetime
```

Sample Data in the table

```
id  BookingDate         BookedStartTime     BookedEndTime
1   2014-02-03 00:00:00 2014-02-03 08:30:00 2014-02-03 09:00:00
2   2014-02-03 00:00:00 2014-02-03 09:00:00 2014-02-03 10:30:00
3   2014-02-03 00:00:00 2014-02-03 12:00:00 2014-02-03 14:30:00
4   2014-02-03 00:00:00 2014-02-03 15:00:00 2014-02-03 16:30:00
```

If I give a input parameters as

```
BookingDate  : 2014-02-03    
DurationCode : 1 (eg 30 minutes)
```

I would like to get the result as below

```
2014-02-03 08:00:00     2014-02-03 08:30:00
2014-02-03 10:30:00     2014-02-03 11:00:00
2014-02-03 11:00:00     2014-02-03 11:30:00
2014-02-03 11:30:00     2014-02-03 12:00:00
2014-02-03 14:30:00     2014-02-03 15:00:00
2014-02-03 16:30:00     2014-02-03 17:00:00
```

If the input parameters are

```
BookingDate  : 2014-02-03    
DurationCode : 2 (eg 15 minutes)
```

The results should be like given below

```
2014-02-03 08:00:00     2014-02-03 08:15:00
2014-02-03 08:15:00     2014-02-03 08:30:00
2014-02-03 10:30:00     2014-02-03 10:45:00
2014-02-03 10:45:00     2014-02-03 11:00:00
2014-02-03 11:00:00     2014-02-03 11:15:00
2014-02-03 11:15:00     2014-02-03 11:30:00
2014-02-03 11:30:00     2014-02-03 11:45:00
2014-02-03 11:45:00     2014-02-03 12:00:00
2014-02-03 14:30:00     2014-02-03 14:45:00
2014-02-03 14:45:00     2014-02-03 15:00:00
2014-02-03 16:30:00     2014-02-03 16:45:00
2014-02-03 16:45:00     2014-02-03 17:00:00
```

The start and end appointment are 08:00 and 18:00

I have written a stored procedure for the same, which seems to be working, but I would like to know if there is any simple way to do the same.

The Stored Procedure is

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[FindAvailableTime] (
  @BookingDate datetime,
  @DurationCode int
)
as
Declare @Duration datetime
Declare @DurationMinutes int
Declare @DurationHours int

select @Duration = Duration from DurationCode where DurationCodeID = @DurationCode

Set @DurationMinutes = datepart(minute,@Duration)
Set @DurationHours = datepart(hour,@Duration)
if (@DurationHours > 0) 
Begin
 Set @DurationMinutes = @DurationMinutes + (@DurationHours * 60)
End

Declare @StartTimeHR int
Declare @StartTimeMN int
Declare @EndTimeHR int
Declare @EndTimeMN int

Declare @CurrentDateTimeStart datetime
Declare @CurrentDateTimeStartString varchar(100)
Declare @CurrentDateTimeEnd datetime
Declare @CurrentDateTimeEndString varchar(100)
Declare @CurrentDateTimeEndWork datetime
Declare @CurrentDateTimeEndStringWork varchar(100)


Declare @CurrentYear int
Declare @CurrentMonth int
Declare @CurrentDay int

Set @CurrentYear = datepart(year,@BookingDate)
Set @CurrentMonth = datepart(month,@BookingDate)
Set @CurrentDay = datepart(day,@BookingDate)

Set @StartTimeHR = 8
Set @StartTimeMN = 0
Set @EndTimeHR = 18
Set @EndTimeMN = 1
Set @CurrentDateTimeStartString = convert(varchar(10),@CurrentYear) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@CurrentMonth) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@CurrentDay) + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),@StartTimeHR) + ':' + convert(varchar(10),@StartTimeMN) + ':' + '0'
Set @CurrentDateTimeEndString = convert(varchar(10),@CurrentYear) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@CurrentMonth) + '-' + convert(varchar(10),@CurrentDay) + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),@EndTimeHR) + ':' + convert(varchar(10),@EndTimeMN) + ':' + '0'
set @CurrentDateTimeStart = convert(datetime, @CurrentDateTimeStartString)
set @CurrentDateTimeEnd = convert(datetime, @CurrentDateTimeEndString)

Declare @CurrentDateTimeEndTemp datetime
set @CurrentDateTimeEndTemp = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@CurrentDateTimeStart)

Declare @AppointmentStartTime datetime
Declare @AppointmentEndTime datetime

Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime
Declare @EndDateTemp datetime

Declare @StartDatePlusOne datetime
Declare @EndDateMinusOne datetime

set @StartDate = @CurrentDateTimeStart
set @EndDate = @CurrentDateTimeEnd
set @EndDateTemp = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@StartDate)

Set @StartDatePlusOne = dateadd(mi,1,@StartDate)
Set @EndDateMinusOne = DateAdd(mi,-1,@EndDateTemp)

Create Table #Appointment_AvailableTime (StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime)

if Exists (select * from tblAppointments where BookingDate = @BookingDate)
Begin
while (@EndDateTemp < @EndDate) 
Begin
    if not exists (Select * from tblAppointments where @StartDatePlusOne between BookedStartTime and BookedEndTime or @EndDateMinusOne between BookedStartTime and BookedEndTime)
    begin
         if not exists (Select * from tblAppointments where BookedStartTime Between @StartDatePlusOne and @EndDateMinusOne or BookedEndTime between @StartDatePlusOne and @EndDateMinusOne)
          Begin
           insert into #Appointment_AvailableTime values(@StartDate, @EndDateTemp)
           set @StartDate = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@StartDate)
          End
         Else
          Begin
           Select @StartDate = max(BookedEndTime) from tblAppointments where BookedStartTime Between @StartDatePlusOne and @EndDateMinusOne or BookedEndTime between @StartDatePlusOne and @EndDateMinusOne
          End

          set @EndDateTemp = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@StartDate)
          Set @StartDatePlusOne = dateadd(mi,1,@StartDate)
          Set @EndDateMinusOne = DateAdd(mi,-1,@EndDateTemp)
    End
    Else
    Begin
         Select @StartDate = max(BookedEndTime) from tblAppointments where @StartDatePlusOne between BookedStartTime and BookedEndTime or @EndDateMinusOne between BookedStartTime and BookedEndTime
         set @EndDateTemp = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@StartDate)
         Set @StartDatePlusOne = dateadd(mi,1,@StartDate)
         Set @EndDateMinusOne = DateAdd(mi,-1,@EndDateTemp)
    End
End
End
Else
Begin
Set @CurrentDateTimeEndWork = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@CurrentDateTimeStart)  
while (@CurrentDateTimeStart < @CurrentDateTimeEnd and @CurrentDateTimeEndWork < @CurrentDateTimeEnd)
Begin
    insert into #Appointment_AvailableTime values(@CurrentDateTimeStart, @CurrentDateTimeEndWork)
    set @CurrentDateTimeStart = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@CurrentDateTimeStart)
    Set @CurrentDateTimeEndWork = dateadd(mi,@DurationMinutes,@CurrentDateTimeStart)
End
End
select StartTime, EndTime from #Appointment_AvailableTime
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a table that holds all valid appointment times.  Putting all possible 1h, 30m, 15m slots during an 10 hour period is still tiny (70 rows).  This makes adding more complex rules, like "no 1 hour appointments after 4pm" really easy.  Adding a day-of-the-week column to the lookup table will let you trivially add things like "extended hours on wednesdays" or "half day saturdays".

```
CREATE TABLE tblAppointmentSlots (
  DurationID    int,
  SlotStartTime datetime CHECK (CAST(SlotStartTime AS int) = 0),
  SlotEndTime   datetime CHECK (CAST(SlotEndTime   AS int) = 0)
)
GO

INSERT tblAppointmentSlots VALUES
(1, '08:00', '08:30'),
(1, '08:30', '09:00'),
etc..
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[FindAvailableTime] (
  @BookingDate datetime,
  @DurationCode int
)
AS
SELECT
  @BookingDate + SlotStartTime,
  @BookingDate + SlotEndTime
FROM tblAppointmentSlots
WHERE DurationID = @DurationCode
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblAppointments
    WHERE @BookingDate + SlotStartTime < BookedEndTime
      AND @BookingDate + SlotEndTime   > BookedStartTime
)
```